# liferay login via curl

Tags: curl, post, liferay

I've got several user accounts on a liferay instance that I need to register.  I've got their usernames and passwords in a vault and want to script their registration because using webservices with those usernames and passwords seems to be tied to logging in once with them.

I've been trying to screen scrape my login screen and generate a post request with curl, but it's not working.

here's my "one-liner"

```
password=$(grep "PASSWORD" /etc/default/website_creds | cut -d= -f2);
username=$(grep "USERNAME" /etc/default/website_creds | cut -d= -f2);
curl -s https://mysite.obfuscated_company_name.com |\
    grep -o 'form action="https://mysite.obfuscated_company_name.com/home;jsessionid.*Flogin%2Flogin"' |\
    grep -o "https.*Flogin%2Flogin" |\
    sed "s/&amp;/\&/g" |\
    while read url;\
     do curl "$url&_58_login=$username&_58_password=$password";\
     done
```

Is there any chance of this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would be happier if instead of scrapping Liferay, you use its JSON-WS API. Let's see if it would help you.

## Find the operation to use

Just access https://mysite.obfuscated_company_name.com/api/jsonws. If you have success, you will see something like this in your browser:

[image: The JSON-WS initial page. There is an important "Search" input in it.]

There, type `add-user` in the "Search" box. You should get something like this:

[image: The add-user options]

You are going to click in any of the `add-user` options under "User" section. I recommend the second one, that is shorter.

## The method page

Now, you get a page like this:

[image: add-user page]

This is basically a documentation to the `UserService.addUser()` method from the user service.

The interesting part is the form that can be found below in the page:

[image: Form to call the method]

Each field of this form is a parameter of `UserService.addUser()`. When we submit this form, we call this method, saving a new user in the database!

## Filling the form

So, to understand how it works, let's fill the form:

- First, you need the company id, that you can easily find by calling `select companyId from Company;` at the Liferay database.
- The `autoPassword` option should be false, because we do want to define the passwords (they're coming from files, right?)
- Since this is an experiment, we are going to use some arbitrary passwords. Type anything inside `password1`, and repeat it in `password2`.
  ** This may seem a bit convoluted to have to type it twice. You are right, it is. The older Liferay APIs are ridiculously complicated. Sorry. But it is better than scrapping!
- `autoScreenname` should also be false.
- Type some random screen name in the `screenname` field, just for this test.
- `emailAddress`, put an email on it.
- `facebookId` is unnecessary, but since it is a number, we have to put 0 on it.
- `openId` and `locale` can be empty.
- Give it some `firstName` and `lastName`.
- `prefixId` and `suffixId` can be 0.
- Again, put some values in the `birthday` fields. They are numeric, so we need to fill them. Yes, it is convoluted.

Now click on "Invoke." If anything goes wrong, an error message will appear in the "Result" tab. If everything goes well, instead of an error you get the result in JSON form. Something like this:

[image]

Now, if you go to "Control Panel > Users > Users and Organizations", *voilà*, there it is your user.

## Using cURL

The form itself will not help your scripts, of course. The good thing is, besides the "Results" tab, there is a "curl Example" tab. It will contain something like this:

```
    curl http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/user/add-user \
      -u test@liferay.com:test \
      -d companyId=20114 \
      -d autoPassword=false \
      -d password1='pass' \
      -d password2='pass' \
      -d autoScreenName=true \
      -d screenName='user2' \
      -d emailAddress='liferay.for.testing+2@gmail.com' \
      -d facebookId=0 \
      -d openId='' \
      -d locale= \
      -d firstName='user' \
      -d middleName='' \
      -d lastName='2' \
      -d prefixId=0 \
      -d suffixId=0 \
      -d male=true \
      -d birthdayMonth=1 \
      -d birthdayDay=1 \
      -d birthdayYear=1970 \
      -d jobTitle='' \
      -d groupIds= \
      -d organizationIds= \
      -d roleIds= \
      -d userGroupIds= \
      -d sendEmail=true
```

**This** is your curl command. You will have to change some stuff:

- Replace `-u test@liferay.com:test` with the real admin user of your site.
- Replace "pass" in  `-d password1='pass' -d password2='pass'` with a variable.
- The same with the `-d username` option.
- You will problably have to make up some names and emails, because they are obligatory...

Yet, those are details. The API may help you with the hard part.

Comment: I'll check out the API, we are adding the users successfully, but some password-hash field seems to need to be filled in before users that we add can use the API.  The only way we've been able to populate that field is by logging in through the website - maybe this is the question I should have asked.... How to populate the password hash without logging in.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you already created the users, but you cannot get to use the API with them without making them logging in at least once. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what we're seeing